# How to properly use BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName)

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I want to load Bitmap from Project resources using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName)`.But I don't know how `pathName` should be composed. Here on StackOverflow I found some answers but they are about loading images from SD card. So How can I load Images from Project Resources by their paths(for example from drawable folder). I don't want to use `BitmapFactory.decodeResources()` because I have a lot of images. And I want to have access to all. With String pathname it will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know how pathName should be composed.

There is no `pathName`, as resources are not files on the filesystem of the device. They are entries in an APK file. You have to use `decodeResource()`.

> I don't want to use BitmapFactory.decodeResources() because I have a lot of images.

Having a lot of images does not change matters, nor should it impede your use of `decodeResource()`.

Comment: I need to load Image by number. For example if input is 5 load Image named 5,or load 5th image. Or get ArrayList of all drawables.

Comment: @PcAF: "I need to load Image by number" -- so, find the resource ID for your desired image "by number", whatever that means. Use `getIdentifier()` on a `Resources` object for that, where you can call `getResources()` on your `Activity` to get the `Resources` object.

Comment: Imagine that there are images with numbers (0-9), When the input is larger than 0,and smaller than 9 on Screen should appear input+1. For Example input is 5 on Screen should appear 6. How will you do that ?

Comment: @PcAF: Create an `int[]` of resource identifiers. Whether you get those resource identifiers by having `R.drawable.xxxx` in your code, or whether you get those via `getIdentifier()` on a `Resources` object, is up to you. Then, when you need the Nth resource identifier, get it from the `int[]`.

Comment: How to fill `int[]` with resource identifiers if there are more than 100 images.

Comment: @PcAF: As I wrote, whether you get those resource identifiers by having `R.drawable.xxxx` in your code, or whether you get those via `getIdentifier()` on a `Resources` object, is up to you.

Comment: Sorry,I just forgot about `getIdentifier( )`,Thanks for Reply.

Comment: @PcAF: If your resource files are numbered, use a `for` loop to generate the `String` for a given number, fetch the resource ID via `getIdentifier()`, and store the result in the `int[]`.

Comment: Yes, this is what i did. Now I think that i should name this question:How to get resource Id by name. But now i found that there on stackoverflow are already some answers about that.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(R.drawable.test);`? It decodes only the resource you want. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html).

Comment: Because I want to have access to all. For Example I name all images by numbers. And then just change number, convert to String and load image.

Comment: Have you got any idea how to get for example ArrayList of Bitmaps.

Comment: How do you mean that? You could get the resource ID from the R class by reflection and use a for loop...

Comment: I need to load Image just by its Number. So for example if input is 7,load Image named 7,or 7th Image.